# how can i use splitter in pyqt6?

Tags: python, pyqt6

I want to show splitter in pyqt6 but it doesn't work properly

i am using this code to create a layout. in this code i am using pyqt6.

```
import sys
from widgets.tabWidget import TabWidgets
from PyQt6 import QtCore
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QToolBar, QStyle, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt6.QtGui import QIcon, QAction


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('title')
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 400),

        self.tab_widget = TabWidgets(self)
        self.tab_widget.setMinimumSize(800, 500)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tab_widget)
        self.toolbar()
        self.actions()
        self.menubar()

    def menubar(self):
        menuBar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menuBar.addMenu('File')
        fileMenu.addAction(self.newAction)

    def actions(self):
        self.newAction = QAction(self)
        self.newAction.setText("new")

    def toolbar(self):
        top_tool_bar = QToolBar('main_tools', self)
        self.addToolBar(Qt.ToolBarArea.TopToolBarArea, top_tool_bar)
        top_tool_bar.addAction(QIcon('image/add-icon1.png'), 'open new data')
        top_tool_bar.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(35, 35))

class TabWidgets(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__()

        page_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        map_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tabs.setMaximumHeight(80)
        self.tab1 = QWidget()
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1, 'main tools')
        self.tab1.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.tab1.setLayout(self.tab1.layout)

        self.map = QSplitter(self)
        self.toc = QSplitter(self)
        map_layout.addWidget(self.toc)
        map_layout.addWidget(self.map)
        page_layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        page_layout.addLayout(map_layout)
        self.TOC(self.map)
        self.Map(self.map)
        page_layout.addWidget(self.map)
        self.setLayout(page_layout)

    def TOC(self, parent):
        toc_content = QtWidgets.QDialog(parent)
        return toc_content


    def Map(self, parent):
        toc_content = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(parent)
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

and it show me something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNH9M.jpg)

but i want a layout like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnRI3.jpg)
i want to show splitter in full size.
how can i show it???

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. If you don't want the post to show up anymore, then just click that little `delete` link instead.

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts, if you persist it will be locked by a moderator.

Answer (score 1):

You have three main problems:

- you only need *one* `QSplitter`;
- child widgets should not be simply added using the splitter as parent;
- you are adding a QDialog, which is intended as a top level window and should **never** be used as a child widget;

QSplitter is not the "handle" that is used to resize the widgets, it is a *container* widget that has its own internal layout management, and widgets should always be added using `insertWidget()` or `addWidget()` (similarly to layouts); while creating child widgets with the splitter as parent is possible, it's discouraged, as [per documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsplitter.html#childEvent):

> [`childEvent()`] is also used to handle the situation where a widget is created with the splitter as a parent but not explicitly added with insertWidget() or addWidget(). **This is for compatibility and not the recommended way of putting widgets into a splitter in new code.**

The *proper* way to add widgets to a splitter is *only* using `insertWidget()` or `addWidget()`. When a widget is added, QSplitter internally creates a [QSplitterHandle](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsplitterhandle.html) that is directly managed by it. Note that the first handle is always invisible: each managed widget always has a handle at its left (or top), and, for obvious reasons, the "first" widget does not need to show it.

Considering the above, you probably don't need the `map_layout` either, which was pointless anyway, since you are going to use just one splitter (and you also added `self.map` to two different layouts).

You should also be more careful when using the parent argument: for instance, you created the `self.tab1.layout` with `self` as parent, but that is wrong, since that layout should be set for `self.tab1`.

```py
class TabWidgets(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__()

        page_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tabs.setMaximumHeight(80)
        self.tab1 = QWidget()
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1, 'main tools')
        self.tab1.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.tab1) # note this!

        self.map = QSplitter(self)

        page_layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        page_layout.addWidget(self.map)

        self.TOC(self.map)
        self.Map(self.map)

    def TOC(self, splitter):
        toc_content = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent)
        splitter.addWidget(toc_content)

    def Map(self, splitter):
        toc_content = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(parent)
        splitter.addWidget(toc_content)
```